# Implementing POST Method to insert data in MYSQL database using RESTFul web service

Tags: java, mysql, rest, post, jersey

I am trying to implement POST method using restful web service using jersey and  Postman for rest client in java. Now I am unable to insert data into the database using post method. I have table in mysql database name person which has 3 fields. id(primary key,auto increment), firstname, lastname. I made there java classes one is person as model class and PersonResource class for declaring REST api and PersonService for implementing REST method to make crud operation.

```
   PersonResource class is:

        @Path("/person")
        public class PersonResource {
            DbConnection connect=new DbConnection();
            Connection conn=null;

            PersonService service=new PersonService();

            @POST 
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)// specifies the request body content
            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            public Person addMessage(Person person) throws Exception{
            return service.addMessage(person);
        }
        }
```

PersonService class is:

```
        public class PersonService {

            DbConnection connect=new DbConnection();
            Connection conn=null;

            public Person addMessage(Person person) throws Exception {

            Person p=new Person();
            String sql="insert into person (firstname,lastname) values(?,?)";
            conn=connect.databaseConnection();
            PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1,p.getFirstName());
                pst.setString(2,p.getLastName());   
                pst.executeUpdate();
                pst.close();
                return person;
        }
        }
```

I have successfully retrieve person info by person id. Now i want to make post request from postman to insert data in the mysql database.

From postman i made post request and select the content-type application/json in the header and write the data in the raw text in json format.when i hit the send button it getting 415 Unsupported Media Type.

can anybody help me how to capture the postman data to insert into the database or any help how to implement post method to insert record in database using REST from postman? Here is my postman window.
[image]
    Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the url you are posting to?

Comment: @ Scary Wombat Sorry I don't understand your question. is this you are asking? http://localhost:8080/worldinfo/webapi/person. I am using Tomcat server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get an unsupported operation exception your service is probably there and you have been able to fetch it. However the data format is not working in between. This normally happen when you are expecting something different that was sent ( JSON ) which doesn't see the case since you declare to consume a JSON.

My take is that serialization is not working and you are getting String and expecting JSON. For confirming that you can modify or create another service accepting plain text and sending the same request body.

If that is confirmed - jersey should be able to serialize easily simple objects. You just need to add the right dependencies for that. Whether is jackson, gson, etc. Normally you can simply declare jersey-json dependency like below. Make sure some serializer is present.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

check [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) tutorial: is pretty much what you are willing to do.

Comment: Yes this works for me. I have added this dependency and my code working fine..thanks